# Can a CFG parse tree have a root other than S?

Tags: context-free, discrete-mathematics

Can a CFG parse tree have a root other than starting non-terminal S? Except for the cases when tree has a height equal to zero and contains only one symbol from the main alphabet.

Comment: Short answer: no. (As if a tree could have a root other than a root.)